# Visualizing large 3D dataset with scatter plot

Tags: matlab, 3d, data-visualization, matlab-figure, scatter-plot

I'm running a simulation in MATLAB in which I have a large 3D dataset that changes each time step. I'm trying to visualize the data using a 3D scatter plot with points that take on different locations, sizes, colors, and transparency levels as the simulation proceeds. The size and color information are redundant.

Rendering and rotating the figure in MATLAB is slow and choppy. My computer has a 4 GHz i7-4790 CPU and a NVIDIA GeForce GTX 750 Ti graphics card. I am using Matlab R2016a on Windows 7. I checked my MATLAB OpenGL settings and the hardware support level is full. (Hardware OpenGL is necessary for transparency.) Moreover, I'm monitoring my GPU usage using [GPU-Z](https://www.techpowerup.com/gpuz/), and during plotting and rotation, the GPU load peaks at only 25-30%.

Here is my code sample:

```
load sample_data2
channels_matrix = cat(1, channels{:});
num_channels = length(channels);
channel_lengths = cellfun(@(x) size(x, 1), channels);

figure(1);
for i = 1:num_channels
    g = plot3(channels{i}(:, 1), channels{i}(:, 2), channels{i}(:, 3), 'k');
    set(g, 'LineWidth', 1.5)
    hold on;
    text(channels{i}(1, 1), channels{i}(1, 2), channels{i}(1, 3), num2str(i))
end
caxis([0 1])
colorbar
drawnow

numDivisions = 8;
ptsPerDivision = numel(grid_x)/numDivisions;
T = 1000;
numplotpts = 2E4;
for t = 1:T
    plot_signal = nan(size(grid_x));
    plot_signal(sort(randsample(numel(grid_x), numplotpts))) =...
        sort(rand(numplotpts, 1));
    tic
    for i = 1:numDivisions
        temp = plot_signal(dists_idx((i-1)*ptsPerDivision+1:i*ptsPerDivision));
        yplot = grid_y(dists_idx((i-1)*ptsPerDivision+1:i*ptsPerDivision));
        xplot = grid_x(dists_idx((i-1)*ptsPerDivision+1:i*ptsPerDivision));
        zplot = grid_z(dists_idx((i-1)*ptsPerDivision+1:i*ptsPerDivision));
        if t == 1
            h(i) = scatter3(yplot(~isnan(temp)), xplot(~isnan(temp)),...
                zplot(~isnan(temp)), 50*temp(~isnan(temp)), temp(~isnan(temp)), ...
                'filled', 'MarkerFaceAlpha', exp(-i)^0.25);
        else
            h(i).XData = yplot(~isnan(temp));
            h(i).YData = xplot(~isnan(temp));
            h(i).ZData = zplot(~isnan(temp));
            h(i).SizeData = 50*temp(~isnan(temp));
            h(i).CData = temp(~isnan(temp));
        end
    end
    drawnow
    toc
end
```

and here is a link to the [data](https://www.dropbox.com/s/undye2h2irhnvj1/sample_data2.mat?dl=0). Is there any way to speed up the rendering and make rotation smoother? I noticed that fixing the size of all data points to a single scalar greatly speeds up rendering and rotation. Is it possible to keep the size as it is in the code and still have the figure render and rotate quickly?

**Edit**: A [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45527533/linking-plotted-data-with-color-and-size-sources-in-matlab) I posted.

Comment: Does it need to be in real time or can you render it as a movie (.avi) for smoother playback later?

Comment: Real time is not a requirement, but it would be preferred.

Comment: I'm getting about 0.5 second delays between calls in your code (e.g. tic/toc).  What are you at right now?

Comment: When I run the code linked above, the toc command outputs an elapsed time of about 9.5 seconds each iteration. If I fix the size data to some scalar, it drops to about 0.7 seconds per iteration. Are further speedups possible?

Comment: I can make the elapsed time drop to 5.5 seconds, but only if I change your code and put the `drawnow` inside the for loop (which is probably where you want it to see the changes).

Comment: Isn't it better to keep the `drawnow` on line 44 where it is because then, the plotting is only performed once all the divisions have been adjusted? (The divisions are there because each one has a different transparency - most opaque in the back, most transparent in the front.) Otherwise, it would plot after every division is updated. Making the move slows my simulation from an elapsed time of 0.7 s per iteration (with fixed, scalar `SizeData`) to about 5.8 s per iteration.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151174/discussion-between-informaton-and-vivek-subramanian).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like the `timer` function is a good place to try next in order to get  a sense of your simulation's progression and then making an AVI once you are satisfied with how things look.

MATLAB's got some great [documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/timer-class.html) for it with a variety of options for consecutive calls are made and the spacing between them.  Check out the `ExecutionMode` and `Period` properties.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this will solve all the problem, but as a first step I would suggest taking all calculations out of the loop that is used for drawing. Here is a suggestion how to do it:

```
load sample_data2
clf
channels_matrix = cat(1, channels{:});
num_channels = length(channels);
channel_lengths = cellfun(@(x) size(x, 1), channels);

figure(1);
for k = 1:num_channels
    g = plot3(channels{k}(:, 1), channels{k}(:, 2), channels{k}(:, 3), 'k');
    set(g, 'LineWidth', 1.5)
    hold on;
    text(channels{k}(1, 1), channels{k}(1, 2), channels{k}(1, 3), num2str(k))
end
caxis([0 1])
colorbar
drawnow

numDivisions = 8;
ptsPerDivision = numel(grid_x)/numDivisions;
T = 1000;
numplotpts = 2E4;

% -> chnages starts here:

% first loop for creating random indices
plot_signal = nan(size(grid_x));
rand_numplotpts =sort(rand(numplotpts,T),1);
rand_inds = zeros(numplotpts,T);
for t = 1:T % one loop for creating random indices
    rand_inds(:,t) = sort(randperm(numel(grid_x),numplotpts));
end
plot_signal(rand_inds(:,t)) = rand_numplotpts(:,t);

% second loop for drawing the first instance:
for k = 1:numDivisions
    temp = plot_signal(dists_idx((k-1)*ptsPerDivision+1:k*ptsPerDivision));
    yplot = grid_y(dists_idx((k-1)*ptsPerDivision+1:k*ptsPerDivision));
    xplot = grid_x(dists_idx((k-1)*ptsPerDivision+1:k*ptsPerDivision));
    zplot = grid_z(dists_idx((k-1)*ptsPerDivision+1:k*ptsPerDivision));
    h(k) = scatter3(yplot(~isnan(temp)), xplot(~isnan(temp)),...
        zplot(~isnan(temp)), 50*temp(~isnan(temp)), temp(~isnan(temp)), ...
        'filled', 'MarkerFaceAlpha', exp(-k)^0.25);
end

% third loop to calculate all timesteps:
[X,Y,Z,S,C] = deal(nan(size(temp,1),numDivisions,T));
for t = 2:T 
    plot_signal(rand_inds(:,t)) = rand_numplotpts(:,t);
    for k = 1:numDivisions
        temp = plot_signal(dists_idx((k-1)*ptsPerDivision+1:k*ptsPerDivision));
        yplot = grid_y(dists_idx((k-1)*ptsPerDivision+1:k*ptsPerDivision));
        xplot = grid_x(dists_idx((k-1)*ptsPerDivision+1:k*ptsPerDivision));
        zplot = grid_z(dists_idx((k-1)*ptsPerDivision+1:k*ptsPerDivision));
        non_nan_inds = ~isnan(temp);
        inds = 1:sum(non_nan_inds);
        X(inds,k,t) = yplot(non_nan_inds);
        Y(inds,k,t) = xplot(non_nan_inds);
        Z(inds,k,t) = zplot(non_nan_inds);
        S(inds,k,t) = 50*temp(non_nan_inds);
        C(inds,k,t) = temp(non_nan_inds);
    end
end

% forth loop to draw all data:
for t = 2:T
    for k = 1:numDivisions
        h(k).XData = Y(:,k,t);
        h(k).YData = X(:,k,t);
        h(k).ZData = Z(:,k,t);
        h(k).SizeData = S(:,k,t);
        h(k).CData = C(:,k,t);
        drawnow
    end
end
```